# Count specific Column in a ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way that I can count how many items there are in a specific column of a ListBox?

e.g.

```
A     B     C     D
-------------------
a     b     c     
a           c     
a                
a                 d
a           c     d
a           c     d
```

A = 6

B = 1

C = 4

D = 3

I only need to count how many items in Column D for example (not all four).

Comment: Use this formula `=COUNTA(A:A)` `=COUNTA(B:B)` etc.

Comment: in VBA you can use `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear in my question. I have a userform with a list box. I want to count the number of items in a specific column in that listbox, not on the worksheet. Similar to Listcount, but I want to count a specific column. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Hi @JaneDoe after five years down the line, do you have an answer for your question ?

Answer (score 1):

The Listbox has a List property. The List porperty returns a Zero Based array.

- 1st Column is 0
- Last Column is ListBox1.ColumnCount -1
- 1st Row is 0
- Last Row ListBox1.ListCount - 1

```js
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim columnIndex as Integer
Dim totalItems As Double
columnIndex = 0

For rowIndex  = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
  totalItems = totalItems + ListBox1.List(rowIndex , columnIndex )
Next
```

Comment: Apologies, I'm quite new to vba. Where in your answer do you select which column you'd like to count? 

Based on the little table I have at the top. I want; say a Label to display how many items are in column C (the answer should obviously be 4).

How would I do that with the code you supplied? Please bare with me, I'm still learning.

Jane